# ¿Cómo asignar valor a una celda seleccionando los valores guardados en una columna de celdas? EXCEL VBA

Tags: excel, vba

espero que estén bien. Paso a contar lo que quiero hacer.
**Necesito que 3 celdas extraigan de otras valores respectivamente**, *(acá ejecuto una Sub que imprime todo)* y una vez realizado esto, **repetir la extracción, pero de los valores de las celdas que están debajo de las anteriores**. Muestro foto de ejemplo.

antes de ejecutar la sub de extracción, me seria útil un msgbox que me pregunte si quiero continuar con la acción.

esto seria algo así: A2 B2 y C2 son iguales a E1 F1 G1 respectivamente.
necesito que después sean iguales a E2 F2 G2, luego a E3 F3 G3. pero antes de cada extracción/copia, una consulta sobre si avanzar o no.
muchas gracias por la ayuda que puedan dar!!!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pon el modo «Grabar macros», pon (está al lado) la opción de «Usar referencias relativas», y hagas las operaciones de copia que quieres hacer. Ya tienes las operaciones de copia. Solo te queda programar el bucle para pasar todos los registros, y el más importante, las consultas. Pero en este punto puedes enseñarnos el código que ya has escrito, y nosotros podemos saber un poco lo que quieres hacer. Gracias.

Comment: Un bucle for que te pregunte en cada iteración y cuando el usuario diga que no, que salga del bucle.

Comment: Hola gente, cómo están? muchas gracias, voy a investigar el bucle, seguro para el que tiene experiencia es sencillo, les comentare los resultados!!